# Symfony Configuration Default Values

Tags: php, configuration, symfony

I believe my configuration to be correct but I want defaults for my redis port and scheme configurations option but they are coming out as nulls?

Can anyone see what the issue is?

[image]

Here is my configuration.

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('company_name');
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('cache')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('redis')
                        ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                        ->treatNullLike([
                            'scheme' => 'tcp',
                            'port' => 6379,
                        ])
                        ->children()
                            ->scalarNode('scheme')
                                ->defaultValue('tcp')
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('host')
                                ->isRequired()
                                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                            ->end()
                            ->integerNode('port')
                                ->defaultValue(6379)
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

And here is my parameters.yml file

```
parameters:
    company_name:
        cache:
            redis:
                host: dev-sessionstore.companyname.com
                schema: ~
                port: ~
```

Console output:

```
$ php bin/console config:dump-reference CompanyNameCacheBundle
# Default configuration for "CompanyNameCacheBundle"
company_name:
    cache:
        redis:
            namespace:            apps
            scheme:               tcp
            host:                 ~ # Required
            port:                 6379
        apcu:
            namespace:            phpcache
```

I want the scheme and port to use default values but what's causing them to be null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled upon it while Googling a different issue and saw that it was unanswered.

The issue is that you are only specifying how null should be treated for the entire `redis` array, not the `scheme` and `port` values. You specify their default values, but because you're setting those individual keys as null you need to specify how null should be treated for each one:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    // Using an array so the values only need to be changed in one place
    $redisDefaults = [
        'scheme' => 'tcp',
        'port' => 6379,
    ];

    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('company_name');
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('cache')
                ->children()
                    ->arrayNode('redis')
                        ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                        ->treatNullLike($redisDefaults)
                        ->children()
                            ->scalarNode('scheme')
                                ->defaultValue($redisDefaults['scheme'])
                                ->treatNullLike($redisDefaults['scheme'])
                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            ->end()
                            ->scalarNode('host')
                                ->isRequired()
                                ->cannotBeEmpty()
                            ->end()
                            ->integerNode('port')
                                ->defaultValue($redisDefaults['port'])
                                ->treatNullLike($redisDefaults['port'])
                                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            ->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

There's also a typo in your parameters file, it should be `scheme`, not `schema`